# How can I validate my database entry through swing?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I have written a code for insert information into mySQL database. 
Mobile number and email can not be duplicate while entering the data. 
I can implement one ResultSet, but I don't know how to implement multiple result set.

Here is the code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

DBcon db = new DBcon();
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs= null;
try{


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db.DB_URL, db.USER, db.PASS);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    rs= stmt.executeQuery("select email from student_info where email= '" + email_txt.getText()+"'" );
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select mob from student_info where mob= '" + ph_txt.getText()+"'" );   // I'm not getting any error, but here is the problem

    if(rs.next()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Email id already Exists");
    email_txt.setText("");
    }

    else if(rs.next()){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Contact number already Exists");
        ph_txt.setText("");

    }

    {  
    String qry = "Insert into student_info(nam, email, mob, country, city, sex) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(qry);
    String comval = country_txt.getSelectedItem().toString();


    pst.setString(1, name_txt.getText());
    pst.setString(2, email_txt.getText());
    pst.setString(3, ph_txt.getText());
    pst.setString(4, comval);   
    pst.setString(5, city_txt.getText());
    pst.setString(6, sex_txt.getText());


    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully added records");

    rs.close();
    pst.close();
    conn.close();

    }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); 


    }
}
});
```

Can we use multiple ResultSet for checking duplicate entry?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but it's not entering in the if condition

Comment: It would be better if you create a unique key in your table, each per column, and try to insert the data. Then, when inserting the data, the execution of the insert statement will throw an exception when a duplicate mobile number or email is inputted and you should handle them properly. Also, this may speed up the validation against the columns since they already have an index (from the unique key).

Comment: Throwing exception is not proper solution. I want to handle them manually. Suppose you set a attribute not null in the table, since you validate through GUI using textfield_email.getText().trim().equals("")

Comment: It is the proper solution in a multi threaded environment. Think about this: users A and B in different location enter the data from the same person at the same time, they select the *save user* (or whatever name) option and your application will only search for the user mobile and email if exists in the database. Due to a race condition, both threads can perform the select operation for validation at the same time (or approximately) and pass, then each thread will insert data from A and B and... duplicate data!

Comment: I already assigned them unique key in the table. Don't think too much. 
Try to implement the general condition.

Comment: I'm not *thinking too much*, that stuff happens. It is called experience. Now, for your problem, execute one statement per time. Evaluate each `ResultSet` per separate. Currently, you only have one `ResultSet` with the result of the last statement.